# prompt() is False while using pxssh

Tags: python, pxssh

I am using Python 2.7, please let me know how can I resolve this issue.
part of code:

```
     try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login(hostIP,userID,userPW)
        s.prompt()
        print " prompt value .. = ",s.prompt()
        s.logout
     except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
         print("pxssh failed on login.")
         print(e)
```

output from above is `prompt value .. = False`; How can I make it `True`

Comment: From the docs: `Returns: True if the shell prompt was matched, False if the timeout was reached.`

Comment: Thanks, @Drum. could help me. how can I forced it for shell prompt (True) or if False how can I use s.expect('.*[$#]') [set prompt]